# Как реализовать вывод "даты" комментария в виде предложения? (день назад)

Tags: время, php, дата

Добрый день, хочу на сайте сделать комментарии к товарам как на сайте lamoda.ru http://joxi.ru/Gq6qU_3JTJA8Y463FBY всё реализовал, кроме даты. Т.е. мне нужно выводить не дату когда был оставлен комментарий, а количество прошедших дней, недель, месяцев после комментария, в виде предложения "один день назад" или хотябы "1 день назад, 1 неделю 3 дня назад". основная проблема с соблюдением склонения слов в предложении (дня, дней, день и т.п.) Посоветуйте как реализовать требуемую логику? Естественно дату оставления комментария и текущую дату я могу получить.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какой-нибудь фреймворк используется?

---

Я эту штуку делал на Yii, штуку сделал, проект целиком, надеюсь, через недельку наконец доделаю (в текущем варианте в репе он вряд ли запустится, потому что я запустил ведение этой самой репы):

[компонент](https://github.com/etki/BlogMVC/blob/master/Yii/components/formatters/DateFormatter.php) / [сама локализация](https://github.com/etki/BlogMVC/blob/master/Yii/messages/en/templates.php)

---

Если совсем грубо, то необходимо получить число и составить таблицу окончаний или "переводов", как у меня.

Comment: Если честно, такой вывод меня безмерно раздражает. Я не хочу заниматься вычислениями, когда это было - "неделя и два дня назад", тем более что в одном дне аж 24 часа, и никакой информации о точном времени в таком формате нет. Не говоря уж о том, что "час назад" - это с момента загрузки страницы, которая может провисеть в окне ещё час пока снова на неё переключишься, и актуальность подобной информации - ноль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вычисления отнимайте от текущей даты (microtime) дату оставления комментария.
По поводу окончаний найдено на просторах:

```
function plural_type($n) {
      return ($n%10==1 && $n%100!=11 ? 0 : ($n%10>=2 && $n%10<=4 && ($n%100<10 || $n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2));
    }

    $_plural_years = array('год', 'года', 'лет');
    $_plural_months = array('месяц', 'месяца', 'месяцев');
    $_plural_days = array('день', 'дня', 'дней');
    $_plural_times = array('раз', 'раза', 'раз');

$var = 1;
echo $var.' '.$_plural_years[plural_type($var)];
//1 год

$var = 3;
echo $var.' '.$_plural_days[plural_type($var)];
//3 дня

$var = 5;
echo $var.' '.$_plural_months[plural_type($var)];
//5 месяцев

$var = 8;
echo $var.' '.$_plural_times[plural_type($var)];
//8 раз
```

Учитесь использовать поиск.

Comment: Я уже всё перерыл, никак не мог найти то что мне нужно

Answer (score 2):

Дополню к ответу выше как произвести вычисление.

```
$postDate = new DateTime('2014-02-15');
$nowDate = new DateTime('2014-06-25');

$result = $nowDate->diff($postDate);

print_r($result);

//Результат
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0 //прошло лет
    [m] => 4 // месяцев
    [d] => 10 // дней
    [h] => 0 // часов
    [i] => 0 // минут 
    [s] => 0 // секунд
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 130
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это реально лучший сайт по программированию, на 90% вопросов мне здесь отвечали в течении 1 часа.